# custom character for strings on mysql workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

i have a string that contains both characters ' and ", i need to use this strings inside an insert.
The problem is that due to those characters the strings results "splitted" therefore invalid.
Can i change the characters ' and " to some other characters?

Comment: Hi, i'm using mysql workbench.
the table i'm trying to insert is this:

create table if not exists orario (
 id_post int not null,
    ora varchar(9),
    contenuto longtext,
    allegati longtext
)

the command is this: insert into orario(id_post, ora, contenuto, allegati) values(1,"17:33","Contenuto 1 ' " ","");
The command is invalid since it take as a string due to the presence of the characters ' " in the third field

Comment: Since the string doesn't contain the character $ i wuold like to replace ' and " with $ for strings

Comment: _i wuold like to replace ' and "_ -- [Please do](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

Comment: I don't think you have understood my question. The string that i have to insert contain the 2 characters for string so i the command input is invalid.
please check here: https://ibb.co/34SqNxv and see how i'm trying to insert the string " Contenuto1"' " bu since the string contain those special chaacters the command become invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can replace the `'` and `"`.
Take the example below:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( 
id  INT(9) , 
my_string varchar(40)  
) ;


INSERT INTO test values (1,'test"'),(2,'""test'),(3,"'"),(4,'test"');

select * from test;

update  test set my_string= REPLACE(my_string, "'", "&");

select * from test;

update  test set my_string= REPLACE(my_string, '"', '@');

select * from test ;
```

Check the results in demo.

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/87

Comment: Thank you very much